# How to evaluate content based recommendation system

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer, recommendation-engine

I have created a content based recommender, which will recommend 10 similar products based on their description. Now I want to evaluate its accuracy and efficiency. Everything works well till now when I want to evaluate the accuracy of the system. Some formulas that I found on Google just evaluate the accuracy based on rating values (comparing predicted rating and actual rating like RMSE). I did not change similarity score into rating (scale from 1 to 5) so I couldn't apply any formula.

I have used cosine similarity and tfidf vectorizer. When I used surprise for cross validation "no raw rating" error occurred. I need some parameter to evaluate the recommendation system accuracy and efficiency.
Code for tfidf:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

##remove stop words
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

###replace non with empty string NaN
df1['product_desc']=df1['product_desc'].fillna('')

##construct tfidf
tfidf_matrix=tfidf.fit_transform(df1['product_desc'])
tfidf_matrix.shape
```

and cosine similiarity

```py
###cosine similarity
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
cosine_sim=linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

###create reverse map

indices=pd.Series(df1.index,index=df1['product_name']).drop_duplicates()

def get_recommendation(title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):
    idx=indices[title]
    sim_score=list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
    sim_score=sorted(sim_score, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    sim_score=sim_score[1:2]
    p_indices=[i[0] for i in sim_score]
    name=df1['product_name'].iloc[p_indices]
    return idx
```

so need some formula to evaluate content based recommender

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more details about what is the problem you are trying to solve?  What have you tried so far, what is working what is not working?  If you can be more specific, maybe someone from the community can help.

Comment: Hello sir , thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have created a content based recommender, which will recommend similar 10 products based on their description n0w i want to evaluate its accuracy and efficiencyEverything works well till now when I want to evaluate the accuracy of the system. Some formulas that I found on Google just evaluate the accuracy based on rating values (comparing predicted rating and actual rating like RMSE). I did not change similarity score into rating (scale from 1 to 5) so I couldn't apply any formula.

Comment: so need some formula to evaluate content based recommender